# accessing $(this) later in code

Tags: jquery

I am using ajax to make a small voting app. When you click +1 to vote up an item the following code runs, adding one to its vote count then the php returns a reordered list of items by votes. What I want is the voted up item to turn green. The code to change the colour will have to run after the items have been reordered and retrieved.

Below is one the block of code. Text in between is discussing what that particular part is doing.

```
$(function(){
  $(".plus").live('click', function() {
      var plus = $(this).data('plus');
      var dataString = "plus="+plus;
```

The next line of code gets the parent element of the clicked button with class `.heading` and animates its background colour to green to show it has been voted up. This works fine except that you only see it for a second because on success of item being voted up they are retrieved and output again to reorder them by votes.

```
$(this).parents(".itemheading").stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#cdeb8b"}, 100);

        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "bin/processButtons.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {

        $.ajax({url: 'retrieve.php', dataType: 'json'}).done(function(data) {


            var html = data['html'];
            $('#content')
                .html(data['html'])
```

What I want to do is move the line of code to here so that it animates the colour AFTER the items have been voted up and then retrieved. This it no longer works because the `$(this)` needs to be done on the button just after it has been clicked.

```
 $(this).parents(".itemheading").stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#cdeb8b"}, 100); 
    });
      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could also save a reference to the clicked button in a variable and use this in your ajax callbacks: `var self = $(this);`

Comment: Are you aware that [`.live()` is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com)? You should be using `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` instead.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Yeah thanks someone said that. I tried switching over but my code stopped working. Once I get the rest of the app done ill put a serious effort into looking at the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to be able to keep $(this) for use later on?

In which case, you should just be able to store it in a variable:

```
var reference = $(this);

//A chunk of code.

$.ajax({url: 'retrieve.php', dataType: 'json'}).done(function(data) {
    //The HTML stuff...
    reference.parents(".itemheading").stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#cdeb8b"}, 100);
}
```

Should do it.
If you define reference in the function, you should be able to access it inside any AJAX success functions you define within that function (if that makes sense).

The other way to do it is as we discussed in the comments below here - use your PHP to assign each answer a specific ID and store a reference to that instead...

```
var reference = $(this).attr("id");
//A chunk of code.

$.ajax({url: 'retrieve.php', dataType: 'json'}).done(function(data) {
    //The HTML stuff...
    $("#" + reference).parents(".itemheading").stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#cdeb8b"}, 100);
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I want to keep this for later use. I tried your suggested code, unfortunately its not working.

Comment: Hm, odd. What happens with it?

Comment: Could it be that $(this) no longer works because the button that was clicked has been deleted and output again by the ajax before the colour is changed but after the $(this) reference is created?

Comment: Ah, that could well be it... In which case, it might be difficult to get the same one again just from the reference stored from $(this). Would it be possible to perhaps dynamically give IDs to each of the things you're selecting from PHP and just store that instead? Seems like the simplest way to solve the problem. :/

Comment: In the php I could out put the items id to that items html. then use $(this) to get the item and somehow get the ID from that to use with the color change?

Comment: Yep. Give me a minute or two and I'll edit my answer above to show it.

Comment: actually i am already getting the id to use with updating the vote count with this `var plus = $(this).data('plus');`  So i could output the id and use that code to get which one was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `context` parameter to `$.ajax`, to set the context manually.

```
$.ajax({ context: this, url: ... }).done(function() {
   // $(this) still yields the clicked button
});
```

Similarly, if you want to be weird, is also valid:

```
$.ajax({ context: $, url: ... }).done(function() {
    this('#my-button').remove();
});
```

Don't do that, though. I just added it to illustrate how the `context` parameter works.